# UITableView ambiguous height

Tags: ios, storyboard, height, tableview, ambiguous

I have `UITableView` in `UIViewController` built in a Storyboard. So far so good everything is well until the moment I am taking the `viewController`'s `view` and set it as a `subview` for another `viewController`'s `view`.
Here is a little more code how I do it:

```
let notificationsSB = UIStoryboard(name: "NotificationsScene", bundle: nil)
let vc = notificationsSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationsNavigationController")
vc.view.frame = containerView.bounds
containerView.addSubview(vc.view)
```

So I use this `ViewController` on another place and everything visualizes correctly but when I change its frame and add it to another VC's `view` hierarchy the `UITableView`'s `height` gets messed up.
When I open the view debugger I can see that it gives me a warning about the table view height.

Here is what the whole thing look like:
[image: [here is what the whole thing look like]

A little from the storyboard:
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I tried to make everything from the beginning creating a new `UIViewController` in the same storyboard and so on but nothing gave me results. 
Thank you

Comment: When are you adding your vc's view as subview? On `viewDidload`?

Comment: @FahriAzimov, yes, on viewDidLoad

Comment: Is your "A little from the storyboard:" picture showing the constraints on your `UITableView`? Or the constraints on the `UIView` *holding* the table view?

Comment: These are the constraints of the UITableView.

Comment: It kinda looks like you are constraining the `UITableView` to its superview's `Layout Guide`... but when you load everything into another container, you lose the Layout Guide. Try changing the Bottom Space constraint to be relative to the superview, not to the Layout Guide.

Comment: @DonMag , you are awesome :) Thank you so much, this solved the issue. You should write this like an answer so I can pick it as correct.

Comment: @user3629571 - done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kinda looks like you are constraining the UITableView to its superview's Layout Guide... but when you load everything into another container, you lose the Layout Guide.

Try changing the Bottom Space constraint to be relative to the superview, not to the Layout Guide.